# Boxee is very choppy on TV

Tags: streaming, netbook, boxee

Just got an HP Mini 311 and decided to try out Boxee.  Hooked it up to the TV and attempted to watch the TV show 'Psych'.  It said it was using USA as the source.  Video was very very choppy, un-watchable.

I exited out of Boxee and just went to Hulu.  Loaded up the same episode and it played just fine, no choppiness or anything.  I was using IE8.

Is this something with Boxee?  Do I need a better PC to make use of the application?  Or is there some software/hardware upgrade I'm un-aware of?

I've got DirectX11, Latest Nvidia, Flash 10.1 installed and Windows 7.

Edit:  I did watch something called "Engadget" through Boxee and it streamed just fine.  At least I believe it was streaming.

Edit2: It seems to only be those TV shows, netflix runs just fine within Boxee.  Hulu desktop runs like a dream.  I'm at a total loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've discovered that my netbook (HP mini 311) is merely a single core that is hyperthreaded.  It does not have the horse power to handle Boxee and streaming video.  In fact, just plain FireFox streaming (the same browser that Boxee uses) video is also very choppy.  Not as bad as Boxee obviously but, still choppy.

Expect to need at least a 1.66ghz Dual core to run Boxee at this point in the game.  Maybe when technology progresses it will work but for now, just have to use browsers to stream.

Answer (score 0):

boxee is pretty gfx heavy for me. I use julu and xbmc for media playback and that works fine, but boxee only works on my machines with beefer gfx cards.

Comment: I wanted to use boxee because it seemed like a nice simple aggregator for internet tv, do julu and xbmc provide a similar function just through a browser?

Comment: xbmc is more of a media center setup so its more dvd's and mp3s than youtube and facebook.  - im looking for a boxee alternative (for the choppiness reason actually) so do shout if you dig anything up

Comment: I found a series of steps that may (or may not) improve Boxee performance.  Mostly a guide to the right drivers.  I'll let you know if it works.